# How do I get this code to work without writing every variable manually?

Tags: javascript

My problem right now is that I have to write every variable and every if clause manually to get every button to work, which is obviously way too much work and it's very limited.

The example code I have works as intended but will get too long very quick...

```
<script>
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        var modalEdit1 = document.getElementById('MODAL_EDIT1');
        var modalEdit2 = document.getElementById('MODAL_EDIT2');
        var modalEdit3 = document.getElementById('MODAL_EDIT3');
        var modal = document.getElementById('MODAL_ADD');
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (event.target == modalEdit1) {
            modalEdit1.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (event.target == modalEdit2) {
            modalEdit2.style.display = "none";
        }
        if (event.target == modalEdit3) {
            modalEdit3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function closeModal(target) {
        var view = document.getElementById(target);
        view.style.display = "none";
    }

    function showModal(target) {
        var view = document.getElementById(target);
        view.style.display = "block";
    }
```

EDIT: Isn't there a way to do it by increments?

Answer (score 1):

If the event.target is the element you need:

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{     
     var modal = document.getElementById('MODAL_ADD');
     if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
     }
     event.target.style.display = "none";
 }

 function closeModal(target) {
     var view = document.getElementById(target);
     view.style.display = "none";
 }

 function showModal(target) {
     var view = document.getElementById(target);
     view.style.display = "block";
 }
```

Comment: That hides my buttons to open the modals as well

Answer (score 0):

Give common class to all modals, then if target has this class all target has parent with this class, hide target/target's parent

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to specifying this behaviour.

Here is example with "hideable" class.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.targed.className == 'hideable') {
    event.target.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```